# Did Michael Jackson do a voiceover in The Simpsons?

Tags: casting, the-simpsons

Did Michael Jackson actually do the voiceover of himself in *The Simpsons* episode *Stark Raving Dad*? I hear that it was someone else that did the voice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Though it had fans confused for years, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_Raving_Dad) confirms it *was* his voice, but that's not him *singing*.

> **For contractual reasons, [Jackson] was credited as John Jay Smith in the closing credits**, and his role in the episode was not officially confirmed until later. Jackson was a fan of the show and called creator Matt Groening one night offering to do a guest spot. Jackson pitched several story ideas for the episode and wrote the song "Happy Birthday Lisa" that is featured in the plot. **He also stipulated that he would provide Kompowsky's speaking voice, but his singing voice would be performed by a sound-alike (Kipp Lennon) because he wanted to play a joke on his brothers.**

[CBR elaborates](http://www.cbr.com/tv-legends-revealed-did-michael-jackson-actually-sing-on-the-simpsons/):

> **The producers agreed [to Jackson's terms]**, although as it turned out, they were so annoyed by having to evade questions about whether it was actually Jackson doing the voice they made a rule that, from that point on, all guest voices on The Simpsons would have to be willing to be credited under their actual name.
>
> Just to add extra confusion to the situation, when it came time to record the episode, while the impersonator, Kipp Lennon, performed the songs in the episodes, **Jackson decided to also record the songs, just for fun.** As a result, there has always been some murkiness, even among Simpsons staffers, as to whether any of Jackson’s performances were used on the final show. **The Simpsons music editor Chris Ledesma, however, has confirmed that it was only Lennon’s performances used on the actual show.**

Here's Dan Castellaneta (Homer) discussing Michael Jackson's involvement in the episode: